# How to add CORS-Header to my esp32 webserver

Tags: javascript, webserver, iot, esp32, arduino-ide

I have the Problem that I cannot fetch() from my created .json because of an Access-Control-Allow-Origin Error. I found out that I have to create some kind of a header, but I have no idea how such a command looks like with my used librarys and which parameters have to be selected. I hope you can help me with the needed addition to this code.

```
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WebServer.h>
#include <DHT.h>

#define DHTPIN 13
#define DHTTYPE DHT11

DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

const char *ssid = "XXX";
const char *pwd = "XXX";

StaticJsonDocument<250> jsonDocument;
char buffer[250];

float temperature;
float humidity;

WebServer server(80);

void setup() {
dht.begin();
Serial.begin(9600);
Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());  
Serial.print("Connect to: ");
Serial.println(ssid);
WiFi.begin(ssid, pwd);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(500);
  }
Serial.print("Connected. IP: ");
Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
setup_routing();
}

void setup_routing(){
  server.on("/sensor", getEnv);
  sendHeader()
  server.begin();
}

void create_json(char *tag, float value, char *unit){
  jsonDocument.clear();
  jsonDocument["type"] = tag;
  jsonDocument["value"] = value;
  jsonDocument["unit"] = unit;
  serializeJson(jsonDocument, buffer);
}

void add_json_object(char *tag, float value, char *unit){
  JsonObject obj = jsonDocument.createNestedObject();
  obj["type"] = tag;
  obj["value"] = value;
  obj["unit"]  = unit;
}

void read_sensor_data(void * parameter) {
     for (;;) {
     temperature = dht.readTemperature();
     humidity = dht.readHumidity();
     }
     delay(2000);  
}

void getEnv() {
  float temperature = dht.readTemperature();
  float humidity = dht.readHumidity();
  
  jsonDocument.clear();
  add_json_object("temperature", temperature, "°C");
  add_json_object("humidity", humidity, "%");
  
  serializeJson(jsonDocument, buffer);
  server.send(200, "application/json", buffer);
}

void loop() {
server.handleClient();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fact is, you don't need to. The `WebServer` it self has API to automatically send CORS header. All you need to do is enable it in the setup. See example below:

```
void setup_routing(){
  server.enableCORS(); //This is the magic
  server.on("/sensor", getEnv);
  server.begin();
}
```

Feel free to comment if this is not working. I'll update my answer later.